# fill textbox from other textbox based on combobox selection

Tags: javascript, acrobat

[Example of forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neBhb.jpg)I would like to know if anyone can help me on the following problem?
I am working in Acrobat Pro with form development.

I have 2 forms in one document, 1 with only textboxes the other with 1 dropdownbox and 2 textboxes.

My knowledge of Acrobare Pro Java is quite small. I think it should be something like this. However this doesn't work in Java.

This code is placed in the custom calculation script of the textbox i would like to fill.

```
//if the dropdownDoc value is equal to the DocumentnrTXT it needs to fill `this textbox with the text from TitleTXT1.`

if(this.getField("dropdownDoc").value == " ") { event.value = ""; } 
else if (this.getField("dropdownDoc").value == "DocumentnrTXT1")
{event.value = this.getField("TitleTXT1").ValueAsString; }
else if (this.getField("dropdownDoc").value == "DocumentnrTXT2")
{event.value = this.getField("TitleTXT2").ValueAsString; }
```

Anyone that can give me a tip on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for is "valueAsString"... lowercase "v". Otherwise, the script looks good.

And it's JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I changed this text,but it doesn't change the output. The problem is that the textbox that i placed this code in just copies the Dropdownbox text on selection. But i want the textbox to display the "TitleTXTxx" text based on the selection made in the dropdownbox. Please check the picture i added to the question today. If i select the text "8977" from the dropdownbox i want the textbox to display "Run". Now it displays "8977" too.

Comment: Ah... Ok - The items in a dropbox in PDF can have one of two values, the first is an array of strings in which case the value and what gets displayed in the list are the same. The second is an array of two item arrays where the first element of the inner array is the label, and the second is the value. So in your example, the label would be 8977 but it's value would be "Run". The same script would then work as you expected.